# Navigation from AppDelegate to a view controller don't disable the audio playing of previous view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

i am a newbie in iOS programming. I am having a problem with navigation controller. My rootViewController is 'WelcomeViewController'. I navigate to 'AbcViewController' from the root view & when the 'AbcViewController' is loaded it plays an audio file. But when i receive an special message into my 'AppDelegate' class, i am pushing into XyzViewController from the AppDelegate class. But the problem is the audio playing of AbcViewController continues playing though the current view is showing the XyzViewController. But the player shouldn't play while the visible controller is XyzViewController. I think there is a problem with my navigation. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Stop audio playback in `viewWillDisappear:` / `viewDidDisappear:` in your `WelcomeViewController`.

Comment: @Robert Audio is not playing though in WelcomeViewController, i checked your suggestion in both WelcomeViewController & AbcViewController. But didn't worked. Actually i think my AbcViewController is working in background even after pushing into XyzViewController. How can i disable it?

Comment: Sorry, should be in `AbcViewController`. But how do you play audio? Just stop it when leaving `AbcViewController`.

Comment: yes, i am using [audioPlayer stop] in my viewDidDisappear.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by Robert, you need to stop audio in AbcViewController viewWillDisapper:

Hope that help.